# Two language angular builds, one ok one with error

Tags: angular7, angular-i18n

I have two almost identical lines in the script section of my package.json:

```
"build-i18n:de": "ng build --output-path=../m_access/dist/de --aot --prod --base-href /de/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.de.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --i18n-locale=de",
"build-i18n:en": "ng build --output-path=../m_access/dist/en --aot --prod --base-href /en/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --i18n-locale=en",
```

The `npm run build-i18n` succeeds, the german one `npm run build-i18n:de` fails with an error message `ERROR in Cannot read property 'start' of null`.

How to find such an error, which is ok in one language, but not in another?

**EDIT-1**

```
angular-version:
Angular CLI: 7.1.3
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.3
... cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.3
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.3
@angular/animations               7.1.4
@angular/cdk                      7.2.0
@angular/material                 7.2.0
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.3
@schematics/angular               7.1.3
@schematics/update                0.11.3
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1

$ npm --version
6.5.0
$ node --version
v8.11.3
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the root cause of this issue, it was a missing / in the closing part of target:

```
<target>Password<target>
```

has to be

```
<target>Password</target>
```

Hopefully this can help others with similar issue.